# 'ERROR: relation does not exist at character', error in celery with django

Tags: django, django-models, celery, django-celery, celerybeat

I have a model called UserApp, of which I make a query from an asynchronous task with Celery, but I get the following error from the output of the docker compose.

> postgres_1     | ERROR:  relation "users_userapp" does not exist at
>   character 536
>
> celery_1       | django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation
>   "users_userapp" does not exist

This is the code of the task:

```
@app.task(bind=True, default_retry_delay=50, max_retries=10, ignore_result=False)
def send_reset_password_email_task(self, muser):
    user = UserApp.objects.get(pk=muser.get('id'))
    print("send_reset_password_email_task user: ",user)
```

that query from the views runs without problems, in the same way if I call the task synchronously without the delay from the view, it also runs without problems, I have already run the migrations and the problem is not fixed either.

I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Did you restart celery after adding model/running migrations?

Comment: yes, I rebuilt all the services with the docker compose included the app with django

Comment: did you added `UserApp` to `INSTALLED_APPS` ?

Comment: @JPG yes, even in the views the query works well

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem, it was due to a bad configuration in the docker compose file, this was my file.

```
version: '2'

volumes:   postgres_data_develop: {}   postgres_backup_develop: {}

services:   postgres:
    build: ./compose/postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data_develop:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - postgres_backup_develop:/backups
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=cxc_web
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/django/Dockerfile-dev
    command: python /app/manage.py runserver_plus 0.0.0.0:8000
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=cxc_web
      - USE_DOCKER=yes
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    links:
      - postgres

  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"

  #celery   celery:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/django/Dockerfile-dev
    command: celery -A config.settings worker -l info
    #command: ./celery/run_celery.sh
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      #- .:/code
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis   celery-beat:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/django/Dockerfile-dev
    command: celery -A config.settings beat -l info
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
```

due to the configuration of 'environment: - POSTGRES_USER = cxc_web', in the django service the app was connected to the 'cxc_web' database, while the other services were connected to the database with the service's default name, which in this case is called postgres. so to the two celery micerservicios also add 'environment: - POSTGRES_USER = cxc_web', and fix the problem.